# Accept bitcoin easily without strict terms of services?

Tags: bitcoind, payment-processors, gambling

I'm interested in starting a gambling site, it has been difficult to find an easy way to handle user funds.

Solutions such as Bitpay or Coinbase disallow usage for gambling.

BIP32 blockchain notifiers like Mycelium Gear appear to be vulnerable to spam attacks and difficult to scale.

I've looked into interacting with a full node but things seem to get complicated very quickly at scale.

Comment: its a very general question. You can accept bitcoin by giving a qrcode of an address to user in your website and put a listener on that address through a simple API like blockchain.info (If you dont wanna run your full node) that gets triggered when the address gets a transaction. That's what bitpay does and it very simple

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a webshop app using armory daemon. It can generate bitcoin addresses on the fly and not put any funds at risk since it's using a watch-only wallet:

https://github.com/goatpig/BitcoinArmory/tree/master/webshop

If you're not afraid of a little code, this should work without having any dependency on external services.

Answer (score 1):

For a gaming website you should use bitcoind JSON-RPC. Pretty much every API service frowns on gaming sites, so it's best just to host your own.

If you 100% want to use an API maybe try blocktrail, I don't believe they are as strict about gaming usage. Also block.io, however there's a monthly fee, but their API is one of the easiest to setup and use.

In my book, [Building Bitcoin Websites](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/153494544X), I go over creating a simple gaming site and it uses bitcoind JSON-RPC to handle funds.